# Looking for a better data structure for bank account program C++

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, bank

I need to create a bank account program which allows users to create an account with as many sub-savings accounts as they want. I have used the following data structure:

```
vector <pair <int, vector <SavingsAccount*>>> accVec;
```

So basically, the vector pairs up account numbers with a vector of sub-account objects. Should I replace the "vector" with something like list, queue or set to improve efficiency? I'm looking forward to finding the best data structure.

Program requirements:

1. Ask user if he wants to open an account
2. If yes,
3. ask if he wants to open a sub-account,
4. if yes, ask for the balance
5. repeat step 3 until the answer is no
6. Create the account with one account-number and all sub-accounts
7. repeat step 1 until the answer is no
8. print the total number of sub-accounts
9. sort accounts based on their aggregated balance
10. Ask for an account number and delete that account if it exists
11. Ask for an account number, if it exists, ask in which sub-account he wants to do a deposit. Ask for the deposit amount and deposit it in the correct sub-account

Comment: You should at least wrap that vector into it's own `BankAccount` class, and expose the valid operations on it as class member functions.

Comment: Please post the operations that you are supposed to be performing on the data structure.

Comment: I already have a bank class and a derived savings class with all the required functions. As for the operations, I have updated the post.

Comment: Make it, then make it right, then make it fast, in that order. The "right" part is problematic at the moment. What does the outer vector represent? A single account? All accounts of one customer? All accounts of all customers of the bank?

Comment: The outer vector basically just stores all accounts and the respective sub-savings accounts of one customer.

Comment: How about ,`map<int,vector<SavingsAccount*>>` or `multimap<int, SavingsAccount*>`?

Comment: Is using an actual database an option?

Comment: What makes a data structure "best"? Speed or easy to use?

Comment: You don't ask for the balance of the main account? Or are you forced to have at least one subaccount?

Comment: I cannot sort map keys which represent account IDs based on the aggregated balance of all sub accounts. Using a database is not an option. I'm looking for a data structure that is faster than the one I am already using. Would replacing both the "Vector" in my data structure with a specific set, list, queue or deque combination be any faster?

Comment: I can have as many main accounts and sub-accounts I want, but I cannot add balance to the main account.

Comment: So if it's a collection of accounts for one customer, perhaps it should look like `std::vector<Account>`, or maybe `std::map<int, Account>`, and reside in `class Customer`.